# linker: main_tests.cpp.o file not recognized; file format

Tags: clang, c++20, ld, ubuntu-22.04

My c++20 CMake-based project builds fine and links the build files just fine normally as well. However, I seem to get this error sporadically:

```
CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

I have had this problem before and managed to get rid of it via cleaning the build and rebuilding. This time around it is a persistent problem for me though. The full error log reads (with linker verbose output):

```
: && /usr/bin/clang++ -g -v CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_gridworld.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_box.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_discrete.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_multidiscrete.cpp.o -o reinforce_tests_all -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/lib   -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/lib   -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/lib   -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/lib   -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/lib  libreinforce++.a  /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/lib/libspdlogd.a  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so  /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/lib/libgtestd.a  -lpthread  /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/lib/libfmtd.a  -lm  /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so && :
Ubuntu clang version 16.0.6 (++20231112100510+7cbf1a259152-1~exp1~20231112100554.106)
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/13
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/13
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -EL -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m aarch64linux -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -o reinforce_tests_all /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/13/crtbeginS.o -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/lib -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/lib -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/lib -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/lib -L/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/lib -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/13 -L/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_gridworld.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_box.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_discrete.cpp.o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/libreinforce/test_space_multidiscrete.cpp.o -rpath /home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/lib:/home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/lib libreinforce++.a /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/lib/libspdlogd.a /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/lib/libgtestd.a -lpthread /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/lib/libfmtd.a -lm /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/13/crtendS.o /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Other solutions here typically suggest to do `make clean`, but as I said this is not solving the problem for me. Inspecting the file also shows nothing suspicious as far as I can tell (but I am also not well versed in the ways of the linkers):

```
╰─ file reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o                                                                
reinforce_tests_all.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o: LLVM IR bitcode

╰─ /usr/bin/ld --version                                                                                                                                   ─╯
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

I am working on macos (arm64) but operating inside an **arm64 Ubuntu 22.04 docker image** with a **GCC-13** installation and a **clang-16** installation (which is also my cxx compiler).

I hope you have suggestions on how to investigate/fix this problem, would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Here the `compile_commands.json` segment particularly for main_tests.cpp:

```
{
  "directory": "/tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce",
  "command": "/usr/bin/clang++ -DHAVE_CBLAS=1 -DSPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL=SPDLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -I/tmp/reinforce/src/libreinforce/include -I/tmp/reinforce/test/shared_test_utils -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pcg-c4aa2cafcf36e3/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/range0301bf3d76d5d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/fmted8c40f5dd02d/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtens8c3f32033d144/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xtl7161fe009dc21/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/nlohm0567ffc90cfc1/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/xsimd7b0628df207bb/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/spdlo0e2ce77e2e884/p/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/froze7ac551bf2fb61/p/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-python-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/pybin895b9560d7d3f/p/include -isystem /usr/include/python3.10 -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -isystem /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/_deps/xtensor-blas-src/include -isystem /home/root/conan_cache/p/b/gtest79f180a2a4833/p/include -g -std=gnu++20 -fcolor-diagnostics -g3 -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 -flto=auto -funroll-loops -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wold-style-cast -Wcast-align -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winvalid-pch -Xclang -include-pch -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_gridworld.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.pch -Xclang -include -Xclang /tmp/reinforce/cmake-build-debug-docker-clang-reinforce/CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_gridworld.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -o CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_gridworld.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o -c /tmp/reinforce/test/main_tests.cpp",
  "file": "/tmp/reinforce/test/main_tests.cpp",
  "output": "CMakeFiles/reinforce_tests_gridworld.dir/test/main_tests.cpp.o"
},
```

/Michael

Comment: I don't use a mac, but `LLVM IR bitcode` seems weird to me, and on my linux system object files look like this: `a.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`.  How are you compiling that file?

Comment: I am actually inside an ubuntu docker container, so mac is only the host platform for docker. I haven't thought of anything fishy with the IR bitcode output because i know that LLVM uses the intermediate represnetation for its entire setup, but i am unsure if it is the correct ouput then for object files. I have edited in the `compile_commands.json` part for main_tests.cpp.

Comment: Looks like you get LLVM bitcode with the `-emit-llvm` flag, so check your environment variables.  It might also be possible your clang is configured to default to LLVM bitcode, but I'd be surprised if an ubuntu vm would do that.  Try compiling a simple c file (`static void foo(void) { }`) an dsee what `file` says about the object file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arose from using Clang's Link Time Optimization feature (LTO). Apparently, LTO is more compiler specific than I expected: In this mode clang outputs LLVM IR bitcode files and not ELF object files. Since GNU ld cannot work with LLVM IR it crashes. I switched to LLVM's lld to handle the LTO part. To activate these settings as well do:

```
    target_compile_options(
            MyTarget
            PUBLIC  # or qualifier of your choice here 
            "-flto"
    )

    target_link_options(
            MyTarget
            PUBLIC  # or qualifier of your choice here 
            "-fuse-ld=lld"
    )
```